# Pandas Dataframe column value split

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk

I have an excel dataset containing usertype, ID and description of properties. I have imported this file in python pandas in dataframe(df).

Now I want to split the contents in desciption into one word, two words and three words. I am able to do one word tokenization with the help of NLTK library. But I am stuck for two and three word tokenization. For example, one of the rows in column `Description` has sentence-

> A brand new residential apartment at mumbai main road with portable water.

I want this sentence to be split as

> "A Brand","Brand new","new Residential","residential Apartment"...."portable water".

And this spliting should reflect in every row of that column.

[Image of my dataset in excel format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lavo.jpg)

Comment: How about you 1) don't post pictures 2) don't post links to pictures 3) much less links to pictures of _excel_ data.

Comment: And read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: There's an `ngrams` function in nltk that does this pretty easily, taking an argument for the number of words you want to group together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example using `ngrams` from the `nltk`. Hope it helps:

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk import word_tokenize

# Creating test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['my first sentence', 
                            'this is the second sentence', 
                            'third sent of the dataframe']})
print(df)
```

Input `dataframe`:

```
    text
0   my first sentence
1   this is the second sentence
2   third sent of the dataframe
```

Now we can use ngrams along with `word_tokenize` for `bigrams` and `trigrams` and applying this to each row of the dataframe. For bigram we pass value of `2` to ngrams function along with tokenized words whereas, value of `3` is passed for the trigrams. The result returned by `ngrams` is of type `generator` so, it is converted to list. For each row, list of `bigrams` and `trigrams` are saved in different columns.

```
df['bigram'] = df['text'].apply(lambda row: list(ngrams(word_tokenize(row), 2)))
df['trigram'] = df['text'].apply(lambda row: list(ngrams(word_tokenize(row), 3)))
print(df)
```

Result:

```
                     text  \
0            my first sentence   
1  this is the second sentence   
2  third sent of the dataframe   

                                                   bigram  \
0                            [(my, first), (first, sentence)]   
1  [(this, is), (is, the), (the, second), (second, sentence)]   
2    [(third, sent), (sent, of), (of, the), (the, dataframe)]   

                                                     trigram  
0                                        [(my, first, sentence)]  
1  [(this, is, the), (is, the, second), (the, second, sentence)]  
2     [(third, sent, of), (sent, of, the), (of, the, dataframe)]
```